# Change foreground of ComboboxItem when it is hovered

Tags: wpf

I am currently trying to change the Foreground / FontColor of my Combobox items when they are hovered by the mouse. I have tried to set the value outsidde the MultiTriggerCondition, in order to activate it, but it is still not working.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem2.ItemsviewHover.Foreground" Color="White"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItem2.ItemsviewSelected.Foreground" Color="White"/>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItem2.ItemsviewHover.Foreground}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got no contentpresenter in your template so you'll see no items at all when you drop it down.

And you can't see the white text on a default white background.

I've done this just as a style in a sample combo and a fixed colour of red:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Red"/>

                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your goal with an `ItemContainerStyle` instead of a `ControlTemplate`.

The `Template` property provides all the XAML required to display the control. In your example above, you've essentially wiped out all that XAML and replaced it with a trigger.

An `ItemContainerStyle` however applies a style to each `ComboBoxItem`. You can then use style triggers to do your custom highlighting. Here is an example:

```
<ComboBox
    ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```